# Print the Content of *string

Tags: go

There are so many verbs for the `fmt.Printf` family, but going through the documentation (https://pkg.go.dev/fmt) I can't find an easy way to print the content of a `*string` and alike (with something like `<nil>` in case it's a `nil` pointer). I was hoping that `%v` might serve that purpose, but that returns the pointer's address instead.
Am I missing something here or do I have to resort to utility methods everytime I want to write the content of such a pointer value into an error message or a log entry?

Comment: There is no fmt-verb for dereferencing pointers. You'll have to do it manually before passing it over to fmt, or use a custom string type whose pointer-type implements the Stringer interface. https://go.dev/play/p/BCPqayIl42T

Comment: @mkopriva Alright, thanks for the response! To me it feels wrong to bring this behavior into a (custom) type since I'm not sure whether it's expected there (as long as the new type isn't dedicated to that feature ofc). But it's an interesting idea anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not as convenient as a verb, here's one utility function will work for any pointer type:

```golang
package main

import "log"

func safeDeref[T any](p *T) T {
    if p == nil {
        var v T
        return v
    }
    return *p
}

func main() {
    s := "hello"
    sp := &s
    var np *string

    log.Printf("s: %s, sp: %s, np: %s", s, safeDeref(sp), safeDeref(np))
}
```

```
2022/09/06 15:01:50 s: hello, sp: hello, np:
```

`*string` is pretty rare in idiomatic Go. Unless you really need `nil`, I'd suggest just using `string`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Two things though: 1) I need it for creating expressive error messages and log entries, so I'ld prefer `<nil>` over an empty entry. 2) Is it really rare? I mean, it's basically the easiest way to make a value optional, to hint that a value can be left out and to force the user to think how to handle the `nil` case. Or would you advocate for something like `""` and make all places handle this value as `nil`?

Comment: Do you have an example of where you'd be creating a log entry or an error message that would need to distinguish between `nil` and `""` in your application logic? The only place I've ever seen this distinction mattering in practice is with certain database transactions, which `database/sql` provides special types to handle: http://go-database-sql.org/nulls.html

Comment: No, not in application logic, just in code semantics. I use `*string` fields in a `struct` as a hint that the field isn't mandatory (e.g. on initialization), and I use `*string` fields to force ppl. receiving this `struct` to actually take that edge case of an absent value into account b/c I don't know where it's used in the end. Ofc, for both problems other solutions without a pointer are viable, I'm just suprised that it's that uncommon to achieve that with pointers. Anyway, I'm going to accept your answer since it's the only one and I've learned something you about idiomatic Go here. ;)

Comment: Alright, stumbled upon a use case: I have a multiple disjunctive  `conditions` in form of `*string` each, and while  `nil` means "skip that condition" here, `""` means: "unconditional clause, so everything will resolve to `true`". But I agree that this isn't really common scenario.